Why does only one selection work when checking against a table in lua?
I am trying to create a Shop-Keep in minecraft using the ComputerCraft mod. Currently, I have three options passed into my function, but when I try to select one, only the first one correctly breaks the loop. I want to have the player select and option twice to have it go through, so they change their choice if they missclicked. Right now, only the first option updates at all.
function UTOptions(opt)
    local FR = 0
    local max = 14
    local w,h = term.getSize()
    local check = {}
    while true do
        for i,v in ipairs(opt) do
            if(string.len(v)>max) then
                error("Option is too long.")
            end
            if (FR == 0) then
                check[i] = 0
            end
            term.setCursorPos(w-15,i+2)
            if (check[i]== 1) then
                term.setTextColor(colors.red)
                write("*")
                term.setTextColor(colors.white)
                write(v)
            else
                write("*"..v)
            end
        end
        local event, side, mx, my = os.pullEvent("monitor_touch")
        if (check[my-2] == 0) then
            check[my-2] = 1
            for i,v in ipairs(check) do
                if (v ~= my-2) then
                    check[i] = 0
                end
            end
        elseif (check[my-2]==1) then
            return my-2
        end
        FR = 1
    end
end

I've tried to change the values in
local event, side, mx, my = os.pullEvent("monitor_touch") if (check[my-2] == 0) then...
such as using my-3 and my-4, but that only changes which option works, and the others still don't update. I have a feeling that the error has something to do with this part:
            for i,v in ipairs(check) do
                if (v ~= my-2) then
                    check[i] = 0
                end
            end

I can't find a better way to update all the un-selected options to 0.

The issue was with my understanding of the for loop. in this block, the v needed to be i since I wanted to check against the index not the value.
OLD:
for i,v in ipairs(check) do
    if (v ~= my-2) then
        check[i] = 0
    end
end

NEW:
for i,v in ipairs(check) do
    if (i ~= my-2) then
        check[i] = 0
    end
end

